# Create shortcodes within foreach loop (using array)

Tags: php, shortcode, array

I have a custom theme that includes several template parts. I intend to use theme template parts within theme files as well as using them as shortcodes.

To create the shortcodes I am currently wrapping each template part in its own shortcode function. Example:

```
function foo_shortcode() { 
  ob_start(); 
  require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/foo.php');
  return ob_get_clean();
} add_shortcode('foo', 'foo_shortcode');
```

Is it possible to output the shortcode functions using a `foreach` loop based on an array of short code names? All template parts are stored in the same folder.

My current code gives error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$function_name' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '('`

Current code:

```
$shortcodes = array(
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'lorem',
  'ipsum',
  'dolah'
);

foreach ($shortcodes as $shortcode) {

  $filepath       = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/' . $shortcode . '.php';
  $function_name  = $shortcode . "_function";

  function $function_name () {
    ob_start(); 
    require_once($filepath);
    return ob_get_clean();
  } add_shortcode($shortcode, $function_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved issue of dynamic function name by using $shortcode var as function name

```
foreach ($shortcodes as $shortcode) {

  add_shortcode($shortcode, function ($atts) use ($shortcode) {

    $filepath = str_replace('_', '-', $shortcode);

    ob_start(); 
    require_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/' . $filepath . '.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
  });
}
```